# C++ sentence palindrome

Tags: c++

[image]

Hi there I have attached my code below and it is not working. I want to eliminate all possibles except number or character. Also no upper and lower case problem. But I don't know why it's not working even after I've tried this far. Please any help would be appreciated.

```
// C++ program to find if a sentence is 
// palindrome 
//#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>
using namespace std; 

// To check sentence is palindrome or not 
bool sentencePalindrome(string sentence) 
{ 
    int j = 0;
    int l = sentence.length() - 1;

    // Compares character until they are equal 
    while (j < l) { 

 //removing spaces and special characters
    while(j<l&& isalnum(sentence[j])==0)
      j++;
    while(j<l && isalnum(sentence[l])==0)
      l--;

   //Checking if not palindrome
   if(toupper(sentence[j])!=toupper(sentence[l]))
    {
     return false;
    }
   else
   {
    j++;
    l--;
   }


    } 
return true;

} 

// Driver program to test sentencePalindrome() 
int main() 
{ 
   string sentence;
   cout << "enter sentence!" << endl;
   cin >> sentence;
   int result = sentencePalindrome(sentence);

    if (result==1)
        cout << "Sentence is palindrome."; 
    else
        cout << "Sentence is not palindrome."; 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: The shown logic is fragile, over-complicated, and error-prone. It's not worth the time to try to figure out exactly where the logic breaks down. Have you considered the much simpler approach of: 1) removing all non-letters first, 2) now that only the letters remain, take the string and create a reversed second string, with all the contents reversed, and 3) simply compare the first string with the second string? Doesn't that sound much simpler, and straightforward?

Comment: I used the debugger on the website you were using and copied and pasted your code into it. After setting a breakpoint at line 14 right after `int l` is defined, it appears that you are not getting the value you are expecting for `l`. The sentence "I am a cat" makes `l` have a value of `0` and the sentence "hello there" sets the value as `4`. Maybe start from there any try and figure out why the code is functioning differently than expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue appears to be the way you are reading in you input in your `Main` function. Using `>>` in C++ will only read in **one word at a time**, so you are not working with the full sentence in the function `sentencePalindrome()`.

You should look at using [getline()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) instead to be able to read an entire sentence in as input.

If you use the debugger, it is much easier to spot the problem. I took your code above and set a breakpoint right as the variable `l` is being declared on line 13 (you can see the orange dot to the left of the code for it).

[image: debugger output]

When you reach that breakpoint when running the code, you can see that the value of `sentence = "Test"` down at the bottom, even though my input at the command line was `Test the sentence`.

Once you fix how you get input, you can check the logic of your program and see if it functions correctly. If you are unfamiliar with debugging, putting in a little time to [learn GDB](http://www.gdbtutorial.com/) now will save you hours of frustration while coding in the future!

Comment: Thank you, as you said everything went smooth.

Comment: Great! Definitely get used to using the debugger to stop your code at certain points and see what your code is actually doing. It only took 2 minutes of setting different breakpoints in the code to find the issue.